# setting a column name dynamically in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, calculated-columns

I have 2 tables. One called **purchases** with

> (id, month, purchase, storeid)

and the other called **purchases_targets** with

> (id, storeid, target1,target2, target3, target4, target5, target6, target7, target8, target9, target10, target11, target12)

The column names in the purchases_targets correspond to months i.e. target for month 1 = target1.
Normalizing this is not an option for me!!!
What i'm trying to do is something like the following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT

    purchases.month,
    purchases.purchase, 
    CONCAT('target',purchases.month) AS column_name,
    (SELECT 
      column_name 
    FROM purchases_targets
    WHERE storeid = 1) AS 'target'

FROM purchases 
WHERE purchases.storeid = 1
```

Note use of **column_name** above. I have tried this and the result always returns target+month for the target column. I would like to know if there is a way i can make this work in mysql. Let me know if more information is needed. Thank you

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL with `PREPARE`, you can't calculate column names in an ordinary query.

Comment: I have seen examples of what you are saying but all of them do not pertain to subqueries. How would i use the PREPARE approach in my case.

Comment: This seems to be a poorly designed schema. Instead of having separate columns for the months, why not have a `month` column whose value is 1 through 12?

Comment: Took over the project. I cant change the column structure in any way because there is a lot of code depending on the column structure the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to pick up different columns depending on the `month`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.month,
    p.purchase,
    CASE p.month
        WHEN 1 THEN pt.target1
        WHEN 2 THEN pt.target2
        ...
        WHEN 12 THEN pt.target12
    END AS target
FROM purchases AS p
JOIN purchases_targets AS pt ON p.storeid = pt.storeid
WHERE p.storeid = 1
```